# Find the inside and outside relationship of connected components in a mesh

Tags: mesh

I extract a mesh from a method similar to Marching cubes. I want to estimate the topological relationship between connected components.

For example, below, let's assume that we have 4 connected components. One is the outside sphere and inside it there are threes spheres.

I computed the connected components based on the edge information of the mesh. Do you have an idea about how to extract topology information?

---

My Idea is to make a tree where a node denotes an object and edge (a,b) represents that `a` contains `b`. I just compare their bounding boxes. But it can have some degenerate cases and I'm not sure how I can implement this efficiently.

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "topology information" here? Do you mean which components are inside/outside other components?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted. Sorry for the confusion on my question.